# send different emails to more than 200 Recipient on one button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net application and i need to send date notification (by one button click) to more than 200 Recipient that everyone have different date , i made method that send on mail but i guess if i used it in **for loop** more than 200 time may be mail **Blocked by GMAIL**

the method to send mail there:

```
public static bool SendRtLMail(string TO,string FROM,string DisplayName,string SUBJECT,string BODY,string HOST,string USERNAME,string PASSWORD)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            if (TO != "")
                mail.To.Add(TO);
            //mail.To.Add("Another Email ID where you wanna send same email");
mail.From = new MailAddress(FROM,DisplayName,System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            mail.Subject = SUBJECT;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            //mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string Body = BODY ;
            mail.Body = Body;

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = HOST; //"smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

anybody have an idea how to implement this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Do not use google. SImple like that.

Gmail does not like bulk email, and you have built your infrastructure stack on a provider where you are not welcome with your requirments. Besies the fact that this shows neglect from your side, it also puts you into a place where you can not solve the issue without changing the stack.

Either hostyour own email server or look for a service for bulk mailing (which I will not name here, you use google - product recommendations are not welcome here).

GOogle does not like you to send a lot of mails in a short time, so live with that.

Comment: Or build your own sheduling service to postpone the send at intervals

Comment: And hope google has no lower daily limit or realizes you do that too often. Or you need to send more emails one day. I found some online info for a daily limit of 100 messages...

Comment: @Infer-On : how can i do that in asp.net without using task scheduler on windows operating system of server because it make alote of problems and stoped work

Comment: sorry, but You can't, when asp.net process go down(for recicling) you scheduling activity will stop